# comparing state and prop value - error: cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, ag-grid, prop

I have two arrays (one in a state and one is a prop) and both have key:value pairs

if i use:

```
this.props.test.col.forEach(function(element){
    console.log(element.header);
}
```

I will see a list of all the header values in the array of key:value pairs within my prop

If I use:

```
console.log(this.state.gridOptions.api.blahhhh.hasOwnProperty('example header');
```

it will return true if the key of one of the key:value pairs in my state is 'example header'

Both work as expected. I want to compare the state and prop key:value pairs and perform an action every time the key in the key:value pair of my state matches the value of the key:value pair of my prop.

So why does the below not work? All i did was combine the two

```
this.props.test.col.forEach(function(element){
    if (this.state.gridOptions.api.blahhhh.hasOwnProperty(element.header)){
    console.log('hi');
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

In the example code above, if there is a match between the value and the key of the state and prop, then print 'hi' to console

Comment: Use arrow function to preserve the lexical context: `this.props.test.col.forEach(element => ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using 'this.' inside the forEach-callback will have another context.

let's try:

```
let self=this;
this.props.test.col.forEach(function(element){
    if (self.state.gridOptions.api.blahhhh.hasOwnProperty(element.header)){
    console.log('hi');
    }
}
```

Comment: ooo worked! Are there any search terms you can recommend so I can read up about what you just posted? Javascript array context?

Comment: This is a nice post that may help to understand [http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/) or try [https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)